# Identify Context.startForegroundService() source in stack traces?

Tags: android, service

I get this exception on occasion:

> Context.startForegroundService() did not then call
>   Service.startForeground() android.app.ActivityThread.main

The fun thing is I have no idea from the stack traces when or where startForegroundService is being called.  I know it's not in my code, but it could be in one of the 3rd party libs I'm using.  Unfortunately, the stack traces are all but useless.  Of course, I can't reproduce it reliably, that would be too easy!  Does anyone have any tips/ideas on how to track down the origin?

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1790)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is crashing "in the lab", you could look at Logcat to see what service was started ~10 seconds before the crash.

Beyond that, use the "Merged Manifest" tab in Android Studio's manifest editor and see what services are showing up in your manifest (plus, what libraries contributed those manifest entries). That at least narrows down which libraries might be the culprit. If any of those are open source, you could then poke through the source code to see if they seem to call `startForegroundService()`.